# Azure DevOps Pipeline reference current tag in docker push task

Tags: docker, azure-devops, tags

Here is my pipeline configuration file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

variables:
  imageName: 'pipelines-kotlin-docker'
  service-connection: 'service-connection'

steps:
# Gradle
# Build using a Gradle wrapper script
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    tasks: 'build' # A list of tasks separated by spaces, such as 'build test'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: build
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: |
      $(service-connection)
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: push
    tags: |
      test1
```

When running the pipeline I get the following error.

> ### [error]tag does not exist: pipelines-kotlin-docker:test1

The build task yields the following output:
`Successfully tagged pipelines-kotlin-docker:396`

I replaced test1 with $(Build.BuildNumber) in the push task and got the following error.

> ### [error]invalid reference format

How can I reference the tag of the image which has been built by the build task in the push task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Default tag for Docker build task is `$(Build.BuildId)`. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) for more information about Build variables.

You should replace tag:test1 to $(Build.BuildId) in docker push task. You check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs) for Docker task parameters.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push image
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: |
      $(service-connection)
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: push
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
```

Or you can also specify the tag: test1 for docker build task. and keep the tag: test1 for docker push task.

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image
  inputs:
    repository: $(imageName)
    command: build
    Dockerfile: Dockerfile
    tags: |
      test1
```